# how I could download a YouTube video in specific path (downloads folder) with python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm working on a web app python to download a YouTube video, and when I select the download button I want the video downloaded in my 'Downloads Folder'

```
import streamlit as st
import youtube_dl
st.title(" YouTube Downloader")
#Enter the URL
link = st.text_input("Enter the link here")
options = {
        "format": "bestvideo+bestaudio"
    }
 submit = st.button("download")
def download(link):
try:
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([link])
    if submit:
        st.success("successfully downloaded")

except youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError:
    raise st.error('this URL is invalid')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
download(link)
```

[picture of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLZn.png)

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmsNx.png)

Comment: I can see the downloaded files in your PyCharm screenshot (on the left hand side) under `youtube` directory next to your `Youtub.py`.

Comment: It **is** your device.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is doing nothing but print "successfully downloaded" message. What I believe you wanted to do was download the video on submit button click. In that case, your code should be:

```
def download(link):
    try:
        if submit:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
                ydl.download([link])

            st.success("successfully downloaded")
    except youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError:
        raise st.error('this URL is invalid')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I could downloaded it in specific path

Answer (score -1):

Did you try checking in your working directory?
If that doesn't work, you can try using pytube (pip install pytube)

`from pytube import YouTube` 
`link = st.text_input('Enter a YouTube URL to download')`
`yt = YouTube(link)`
`out_file=yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download('sample')`